# how to define a relationship in Yii2 with orOnCondition

Tags: yii2, database-relations

I am logging changes in my database to a table called audit_field.  For a given model I would like to retrieve all the audit_fields for this model as well as some of the related models.

For example:

```
<?php
class Job extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getAuditFields()
    {

        $link = []; // what do I put here to get "1=1" ?

        return $this->hasMany(AuditField::className(), $link)
            ->orOnCondition([
                'audit_field.model_id' => $this->job_id, 
                'audit_field.model_name' => get_class($this),
            ])
            ->orOnCondition([
                'audit_field.model_id' => ArrayHelper::map($this->getJobTeches()->all(), 'id', 'id'),
                'audit_field.model_name' => 'app\models\JobTech',
            ]);
    }
    public function getJobTeches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(JobTech::className(), ['job_id' => 'job_id']);
    }
}
```

What I want:

```
SELECT * FROM audit_field WHERE (...my or conditions...);
// or
SELECT * FROM audit_field WHERE (1=1) AND (...my or conditions...);
```

What I get:

```
SELECT * FROM audit_field WHERE (1=0) AND (...my or conditions...)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer, don't use `hasMany`, instead just return an `ActiveQuery`:

```
<?php
class Job extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getAuditFields()
    {
        return AuditField::find()
            ->orOnCondition([
                'audit_field.model_id' => $this->job_id, 
                'audit_field.model_name' => get_class($this),
            ])
            ->orOnCondition([
                'audit_field.model_id' => ArrayHelper::map($this->getJobTeches()->all(), 'id', 'id'),
                'audit_field.model_name' => 'app\models\JobTech',
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This don't allow you to query the relations of the model like ->joinWith(['auditFields])